# VirtualBox Hardware Virtualization in Ubuntu as Guest OS

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

I have a Windows 7 64 bit and my CPU supports virtualization and I have enabled it. As a guest OS I have installed Ubuntu 64 Bit and I checked Hardware virtualization in VirtualBox but after running this command `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` it returns `0` meaning my hardware doesn't support virtualization. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

No need to worry. The behaviour you report is exactly what is expected.

The **virtual CPU** of your guest OS will not be able to use hardware virtualization the way your real CPU running the host OS does.

Comment: You mean I can install KVM on my guest OS?Because I need that for CloudStack..Somewhere was mentioned that you need hardware acceleration to install KVM.

Comment: No you don't it that way, you use only one hypervisor. According to Wikipedia CloudStack supports Oracle VM, KVM, vSphere, and XenServer. So if you have VMware in Windows use vSphere.

Answer (score 0):

The command is meant to check if your host system supports AMD-V or Intel VT-x, but not the guest system. When your host system is Windows you can't use this command because it relies on GNU or Unix utilities (one could install them via [cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) or other porting projects) and the linux kernels proc filesystem, but you're running a Windows kernel ([co-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Linux) might work, but you'd better forget about that).

Comment: I installed VMWare instead of VirtualBox and it works well and  above command  returns 1.I think there is a problem with VirtualBox.

Comment: So you would be happy if VirtualBox developers were lying to you and make that command return `1`? Do you really want to be able to set up a virtual machine inside a virtual machine? Because that's what this command tells you by returning `1` on a Guest OS and I doubt this the proper behavior.

Comment: No I don't. I have a host OS (Windows 7) and I want to have Ubuntu Os as my guest OS.That's why I've installed Virtualbox to run Ubuntu.I need CloudStack on Ubuntu and CloudStack requires KVM to work properly.

Comment: What you're trying to do shouldn't work in the first place, because its a bad management strategy.